# SQL*plus query not giving correct output?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to select `EXCERCISENAME` and `EQUIPMENTNAME FROM SECOND TABLE` base on the name of `MUSCLENAME` from first table:

Tables:

```
MUSCLEGROUP(MUSCLEID,MUSCLENAME)
EXCERCISE(EXCERCISEID,EXCERCISENAME,EQUIPMENTNAME)                            
EX_MUS(EXCERCISEID,MUSCLEID)
```

Query #1:

```
 SELECT EXCERCISENAME,EQUIPMENTNAME 
  FROM EXCERCISE 
  WHERE EXCERCISEID IN(
    SELECT EXCERCISEID FROM EX_MUS WHERE MUSCLEID=1001);
```

The above query gives me correct output because I use `select` statement base on `muscleid` but when I use `musclename` instead of `muscleid` it gives me a wrong answer. Following is my query:

Query #2:

```
SELECT EXCERCISENAME,EQUIPMENTNAME 
      FROM EXCERCISE 
      WHERE EXCERCISEID IN(
           SELECT EXCERCISEID FROM EX_MUS 
           WHERE MUSCLEID IN(
               SELECT MUSCLEID FROM MUSCLEGROUP WHERE MUSCLENAME='Chest'));
```

How can I correct query 2 so that it gives me same output as query 1 but with `musclename`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your query so the problem must be your data. Perhaps you have some whitespace in your data that you aren't accounting for? To troubleshoot, just run that innermost query: `SELECT MUSCLEID FROM MUSCLEGROUP WHERE MUSCLENAME = 'Chest'` Once that's working the rest should run as expected.

Comment: Yes your query working fine..

Comment: Oh! That's surprising! What of: `SELECT EXCERCISEID FROM EX_MUS WHERE MUSCLEID IN (SELECT MUSCLEID FROM MUSCLEGROUP WHERE MUSCLENAME = 'Chest')`? If that comes up empty, then I would be curious if you have the `MUSCLEIDs` returned in the first query in your `EX_MUS` table OR if there is a mismatch between `MUSCLEIDs` in your two tables, in which case I would be curious what the field type is of those columns.

Comment: What's the return of : SELECT MUSCLEID FROM MUSCLEGROUP WHERE MUSCLENAME='Chest'

Comment: When is use 1st query it gives: EXCERCISENAME                  EQUIPMENTNAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Bench Press                    Bench Press Machine
Pec Deck                       Pec Deck Machine
Seated  Chest Press            Seated  Chest Press Machine
Power Rack                     Power Rack Machine
Overhead Pressess Exercise     Overhead Pressess Machine
Vertical Climber Exercise      Vertical Climber Machine
Full body warm up              Treadmill

Comment: But with second query:         EXCERCISENAME                  EQUIPMENTNAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Vertical Climber Exercise      Vertical Climber Machine
Seated  Chest Press            Seated  Chest Press Machine
Bench Press                    Bench Press Machine
Overhead Pressess Exercise     Overhead Pressess Machine
Pec Deck                       Pec Deck Machine
Full body warm up              Treadmill
Power Rack                     Power Rack Machine

7 rows selected.

Comment: You want to `JOIN` the tables.

Comment: @Muhammad - a couple of people have already asked you what is the result of running just the query SELECT MUSCLEID FROM MUSCLEGROUP WHERE MUSCLENAME = 'Chest' on its own.  That's what you need to confirm for others to be able to assist you.  (My guess is that the result won't be 1001, which is why you would be seeing a difference between the results of your two full queries).  We don't have your database, so we don't know the entire contents of all of the tables .....